# git: list files authored by someone and limit them to those existing in HEAD

Tags: bash, git

We list all the files contributed by certain developer as follows:

```
git log --no-merges --author="SomeDev" --name-only --pretty=format:"" | sort -u
```

The problem with this approach that it lists also files that were created by SomeDev at some point but later removed. How can I limit the above only to those files currently present in HEAD? (Maybe that output can be piped together with `git ls-files` somehow).

Preferably

1. it should track renames also, i.e.: if SomeDev has authored `file_old.txt` and it was later renamed (by him or anybody else) to `file_new.txt` - it should be listed as well.
2. it should list the first(/original) author if a file has several authors (e.g. when it was removed and then readded).

Comment: Scraping this out of `git log` output is beginner awk homework, give it a try and if you hit specific questions about how to do something, ask about that. Generate your log with name-status in reverse, record the first author you see, and the last status,